# Online Poker confusion Texas Holdem

Tags: online

The board showed two kings and two aces and a 5. I was holding a pair of 10s and the other player had a Queen and 3. The game gave him the win with 2 pair (A and K) with a Q high. Shouldn't that have been my win with 2 pair considering I was actually holding a pair in my hand. Or does the A and K pair supersede my hand?

Answer (score 0):

Your best five card hand is AAKKT.
The other player's best five card hand is AAKKQ.

From this, surely you can realize that the other player has the better hand and should win.